# Regex - Reject all alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex

I need to allow a string with max length of 3 to contain between 0 and 3 letters...
Or allow the same field to contain between 0 and 3 numbers.
but not Both!

this filed can be left blank, but it cannot contain an alphanumeric sting.

> AAA - Accepted
>
> A   - Accepted
>
> 11  - Accepted
>
> 123 - Accepted
>
> 1AA - **REJECT**
>
> BB2 - **REJECT**

Comment: `^([A-Z]{0,3}|\d{0,3})$`?

Comment: @juharr That works! Thank you

Comment: If what @juharr made helped you, upvote his comment to give him credit. You can also ask him to create an answer, and then mark that answer as accepted to help others in the future.

Comment: @juharr please submit an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @AGrammerPro No point in me making an answer now that wouldn't be any better than what Mathias did.  Go ahead and accept his if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working regular expression for your needs on Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/rW4zL1/3

`^([A-Z]{0,3}|\d{0,3})$`

It will provide you with the results you requested above.

### What it does

It matches either `[A-Z]{0,3}` or `\d{0,3}`, which means either 0 to 3 upper-case characters, or 0 to 3 digits, but not both.

It will also match the beginning and ending of the string. If you don't want that (and match anywhere in the string), remove the beginning `^` and the trailing `$` in the expression, like so:

`([A-Z]{0,3}|\d{0,3})`

Comment: You really should include the regular expression in your answer.

Comment: Regex101.com does not work well on a mobile. Please post the regex on SO.

Comment: That looks familiar ;)

Comment: Oh come on @juharr - cut me some slack. It's not like regular expressions are rocket science, and for such a simple example, it's hard not to end up double-posting the same expression. I was posting my answer as you made your comment.

Comment: I was simply commenting on us giving the same answer, not accusing you of plagiarism.  Thus the smiley face.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`(^\d{0,3}$)|(^[A-Z]{0,3}$)`